# How does h2o's distributed random forest handle multi-class problems?

Tags: random-forest, h2o, multiclass-classification

The [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html)  for distributed random forest in h2o states that, for multiclass problems, "a tree is used to estimate the probability of each class separately". I can see this in visualising the trees that each class indeed seems to have a completely independent "one-vs-rest" tree.

I am wondering how the scores from these trees are combined into the final score vector - are they just normalized to sum to one?

I would also like to understand why this approach was chosen and how it compares to the usual approach of handling multiple classes within a single tree. For individual classes we see that the performance of the multiclass classifier is typically worse than a dedicated one-vs-rest classifier with the same hyperparameters, even though under the hood the multiclass classifier should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your questions. I try to answer:

- **How are the scores from these trees combined into the final score vector?**
  You are right. For each class, a "one-vs-rest" tree is trained. The final prediction vector is calculated as a prediction of each tree and then normalized to sum up to one.
- **Why this approach was chosen?**
  Good question. But I don't know. It is one of the oldest algorithms we implemented in H2O-3. My guess is it was easier to implement. :) You can open an issue and ask to implement another approach. We are open to improving our algorithm base.
- **Should be multiclass classifier and one-vs-rest multiclass classifier similar in performance?**
  Well, I am not sure. I think it depends on the data, too. Do you have any performance comparisons you can share? Which type of data you are using?